# How to filter by language tag using g.triples in python rdflib?

Tags: python, rdflib

I would like to create a dictionary where the keys are the subjects of the triples, and the values are the objects. I am querying a graph (in this example is `g`) where I have multiples labels, an dI would like to filter only on the english ones. How can I do this?

This is how I am creating the graph at the moment

```
d = {s: o for s, p, o in g.triples((None, SKOS.prefLabel, None))}
```

I would expect to add something like but I can't find the correct syntax.

```
d = {s: o for s, p, o in g.triples((None, SKOS.prefLabel, None), lang="en")}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the filtering by the language tag in your dictionary comprehension like this:

```
d = {s: o for s, p, o in g.triples((None, SKOS.prefLabel, None))
     if o.language == 'en'}
```